Can we listen for global keyboard events in an elctronjs app
I want to listen to global keypresses on a computer using electronjs.
I tried using robotjs, it only has getMousePos(), then tried using iohook but it's installation is an overhead itself.
Now i was using node-global-key-listener but its listner works only once.

Have you tried uiohook-napi? https://www.npmjs.com/package/uiohook-napi It provides bindings for libuiohook https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook/

@DanNagle
Yes, tried almost everything available on the internet. Nothing works

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

use pynput library in python and make it executable using pyinstaller spawn that executable in electron app to get the events in stdout

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
